# Filter duplicates MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not exactly sure of the best way to explain my issue. 
I have a table similar to this

```
+---------+------------+---------------+--+
| user_id | invoice_no |  invoiced_hrs |  |
+---------+------------+---------------+--+
|    1    |    1023    |    8.1234     |  |
|    2    |    1023    |    1.1234     |  |
|    1    |    1023    |    5.8765     |  |
|    4    |    1085    |    6.7654     |  |
|    4    |    1085    |    7.5435     |  |
|    6    |    1022    |    5.6789     |  |
+---------+------------+---------------+--+
```

I need to be able to filter my query without having multiple user_id's associated with any invoice_no. Duplicate invoice numbers are OK so long as there is only one user_id associated with it.

What I am attempting to do is to keep only the rows from the user who has the majority of the hours on the invoice.

Comment: Please, add the desired result.

Comment: `GROUP BY user_id`?

Comment: *"What I am attempting to do is to keep only the rows from the user who has the majority of the hours on the invoice."* - You need to SUM then get the MAX from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    t.*
from your_table t
inner join (
    select
        invoice_no,
        user_id,
        sum(invoiced_hrs) invoiced_hrs
    from your_table
    group by invoice_no, user_id
) t1 on t.invoice_no = t1.invoice_no and t.user_id = t1.user_id
inner join (
    select 
        invoice_no,
        max(invoiced_hrs) invoiced_hrs
    from (
        select
            invoice_no,
            user_id,
            sum(invoiced_hrs) invoiced_hrs
        from your_table
        group by invoice_no, user_id
    ) t group by invoice_no
) t2 on t1.invoice_no = t2.invoice_no and t1.invoiced_hrs = t2.invoiced_hrs;
```

Produces:

```
+---------+------------+--------------+
| user_id | invoice_no | invoiced_hrs |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|       6 |       1022 |       5.6789 |
|       1 |       1023 |       8.1234 |
|       1 |       1023 |       5.8765 |
|       4 |       1085 |       6.7654 |
|       4 |       1085 |       7.5435 |
+---------+------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

It get the user_id for the invoice_no which has max part in the total invoiced_hrs.

Note that it'll return both the users if they contributed equally.

Comment: this ended up working perfectly! thank you! what if I were to only have it return the max invoiced_hrs per invoice?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.user_id = (SELECT t2.user_id
               FROM table t2
               GROUP BY t2.user_id
               ORDER BY SUM(t2.invoiced_hrs) DESC
               LIMIT 1)
```

This will get ALL the rows of the user with more hours invoiced.
In your example that would be:

```
|    4    |    1085    |    6.7654     |  |
|    4    |    1085    |    7.5435     |  |
```

Note that the inner query will return this:

```
|    4    |   14.3089    |  |
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! however, for some reason, I am getting a syntax error near limit.

Comment: @nadleeh It's exactly what you need if you want a wrong answer.

Comment: @GurV I just meant that the output is what i was needing.

Comment: I am still getting an error when trying to use this. but I concluded that I get an error any time I try to use order by.